# How to customize the application title bar for a UWP page

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to set the application title bar of a page visibile all the time for a UWP page and also disable the restore button, but I am not finding anything related to this.

All i could do was to change the color of the application title bar having a code like below

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "TEST";
        ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
        titleBar.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 1, 1, 1);

    }
```

but that was all i could do... Also the title of the application title bar was acting strange since i set it to "TEST" but on UI was showing "ProjectName-TEST".

So, do you know how could I customize (set the application bar title, set it as visible all the time not only when the user moves the cursor on top of the page and disable the restore button (like i could have it in windows forms)) the application title bar of a page for an UWP project ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to disable any of the title bar buttons (minimize, maximize, etc). There's [some discussion about this on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/issues/142) which you can follow.

Apart from this limitation, you can customize the title bar quite heavily by using [ExtendViewIntoTitleBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplicationviewtitlebar) in combination with [Window.Current.SetTitleBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.settitlebar.aspx). In summary these allow you to use custom XAML in title bar:

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
...
Window.Current.SetTitleBar(myTitleBar);
```

There's a good go-to resource on GitHub (created by Microsoft) which show what you can customize: [Title bar sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TitleBar)

> The sample shows the following techniques:
>
> Customizing the colors in the standard system title bar.
>
> Extending the view into the title bar, so you can draw a custom title bar.
>
> Responding to changes in title bar states.
>
> Drawing controls in the title bar (XAML only).

Here's couple other good tutorials about customizing the title bar:

[Easily manage the Title Bar in Windows 10 apps](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/easily-manage-the-title-bar-in-windows-10-apps/)

[[UWP]Take the control of your title bar](https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=1952)

Comment: These documentations are horrible